# Why does this two definition of Hyperplane are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

I cant understand why this defenition of hyperplane

$\left\{ a+x\mid x\in S\right\} $ where $S\in \mathbb{R} ^n$ is $(n-1)$ dimensional subspace and $a\in \mathbb{R} ^n$ is fixed

is equivalent to this defenition

$\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\mid\left\langle x,c\right\rangle =\alpha\right\} $ 
Where $0\neq c\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $<\cdot ,\cdot>$ is the standart inner product

The first defenition is a shifting of the subspace $S$, But why does the second defenition describing the same thing ?

Comment: Try subtracting two elements in the second definition and see what the inner product gives you.

Comment: Do you know that the set $\{u\mid \langle u, c\rangle =0\}$ for a $c\ne 0$ is a $n-1$ dimensional subspace?

Comment: That because you'll get a linear depenecy, So i can substruct $\alpha$ and get $x_1 c_1 +...+x_n c_n -\alpha = 0$ And this will be a $n-1 $ dimensional subspace right ? but I still dont get it why it represent the same as $\left\{ a+x\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\right\} $

Comment: @limitless not $x\in \mathbb R^n$ but $x\in S$. Guess what $S$ is.

Comment: The two definitions don’t represent *the same* hyperplane unless you’ve chosen the scalar $\alpha$ and the vector $c$ correctly.

Comment: @amd Thank you, i really want to visualize it, what would be the right $alpha$ and $c$ that will make them equivelent ?

Comment: Take as $c$ any vector normal to the hyperplane. Then $\alpha=\langle a,c\rangle$. Basically, the second definition says that the hyperplane consists of all vectors that have the same (orthogonal) projection onto $c$.